# Renomear no VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Estou com uma dúvida...

Exemplo: Tenho 3 classes separadas dentro de uma pasta, e nessas 3 classes existe o método "validaNomeTitular", mas eu quero mudar para "validaNome". Como eu faço para renomear nos 3 arquivos de uma vez só? Sempre fico entrando de classe em classe e as vezes esqueço de renomear em tal lugar, o que gera um erro no programa

Eu sei que no mesmo arquivo eu consigo fazer isso usando CTRL + F2 com a palavra selecionada, mas em arquivos separados eu não sei

Se tiver algum atalho no teclado ou alguma extensão do VS Code, me informem aqui por gentileza.

Comment: As classes implementam uma mesma interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem que usar a ferramenta de **Search**, ai vc pesquisa o termo e ao mesmo tempo escolhe outro termo para fazer o **Replace**, depois basta clicar no Btn de. **Substituir Tudo** e da um **Save All**

**Ferramente para buscar e substituir**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Um exemplo** repare nas sinalizações como ele troca o texto em tódos os arquivos que tem a ocorrência do termo pesquisado!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Salvar todos as alterações em todos arquivos** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu certo !! obrigado

Comment: @AlefSilva que bom que deu certo ai! Se a resposta resolveu seu problema considere marcar a resposta como aceita clicando nesse ícone ✔︎ abaixo das setinhas do lado da resposta ;)